# Number format issue add a zero after particular decimal

Tags: android

I am trying to format a price text.

Rs. 58.50

So I am using the following format:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
formatter.applyPattern("#,##,##,##,###.##");
formatedString = String.format("₹" + 
formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(text.toString())));
```

But I get the result as ₹58.5 I am not able to get "0"

How to fix this?

Comment: Why don't you just append the string? Now you're parsing a string to a double and then making it part of a string again. So then you get `formatedString = String.format("₹" + text.toString());`

Answer (score 1):

Use

**`formatter.applyPattern("#,##,##,##,###.00");`**

Try

```
DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
formatter.applyPattern("#,##,##,##,###.00");
formatedString = String.format("₹" + 
formatter.format(Double.parseDouble(text.toString())));
```

Comment: Wow. That was quick. Thanks a lot. I tried only .0 but gave me an error. I didn't try .00 :) my bad!

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Android's standard way for using Currency:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("hi", "IN"));
String formattedValue = numberFormat.format(100222212);  // => ₹10,02,22,212.00
```